# How to find time different with php

Tags: php, time, datediff

I am trying to find time differences between two times. This is the code I have:

```
$ddtcounter1="2014-03-06 20:20:30";

$ddtcounter2="2014-03-07 21:20:30";

$today = new DateTime($ddtcounter2);
$pastDate = $today->diff(new DateTime($ddtcounter1));

$total= $pastDate->h . ".";
$total2=$total.$pastDate->i;

echo $total2; //echo the time difference in hour.minutes form (Exmple:2.1)
```

How can I find the time differences? I have read few guides and tutorials and they didn't help. I read a lot of answers but they didn't work for me...

**EDIT:** 
Example (For who didn't understand the question):

First time: `2014-03-06 20:30:30`

second is: `2014-03-07 19:30:30`

The time difference will be `23.0` (23 hours), because it happened 1 day earlier!

Comment: did u ask same question just before?

Comment: I'm sure he/she did. I distinctively remember it too. @user1844933 --- Must've deleted it. These lines of code I remember `$total= $pastDate->h . ".";
$total2=$total.$pastDate->i;`

Comment: Yes I did because at the first time I didnt explain the question correctly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
$ddtcounter1="2014-03-06 20:15:30";
$ddtcounter2="2014-03-07 21:20:30";

$date1 = new DateTime($ddtcounter1);
$date2 = new DateTime($ddtcounter2);
$diff = $date1->diff($date2);

$hours = $diff->d * 24;
$hours += $diff->h;
echo $hours;
echo $diff->i; // Minutes
echo sprintf('%s.%s', $hours, $diff->i); // Hours.Minutes
```

Comment: This is not the problem... The problem is that it shows the different between the times only. in this exmple its say 1 hour different, its not check the timediff between the dates...

Comment: I, totally, do not, follow, what you mean. This shows `hours` and `minutes`. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want that its will show the date different in hours and too...
If the first one is: 2014-02-06 20:30:30
and the second is: 2014-02-07 19:30:30
the time difference will be 23.0 (23 hours)

Comment: You mean that you want to subtract a piece of the date from each other? I'm sorry, but I do not follow what you mean.

Comment: ok, its almost working! I just need to get the minutes! Thank you!

Comment: Updated. Try again :P